# sscanf, literal or pointer format

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf, string-literals

Let's see this line of C code:

```
if(sscanf(s, "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec) != EOF) { 
    // ... other stuff
}
```

I'm using Microchip C30 compiler. 's' and the other variables are defined before.
The size of my whole code is: 237396 bytes.

Let's try to change the format string from literal to pointer:

```
const char *format = "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d";
if(sscanf(s, format, &year, &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec) != EOF) { 
    // ... other stuff
}
```

The size is now: 243798 bytes! More than 6 kB!

Is it an expected behavior?

Comment: You can't just look at the size of the generated binary, at least if it's in a segmented format (you know, separate code, data and bss segments). Then you have to look at the size of the individual segments.

Comment: It looks like you need to send this to the compiler vendor. BTW, is this Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: I'm using an IDE provided by the vendor of the custom board, which wraps the calls to the compiler. So I can only see the size of the binary and RAM used. The configuration is release (there is no a debug one). For others changes it seems reasonable except for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case the compiler knows what select set of `sscanf()` conversions are to be used: string to `int`.

```
sscanf(s, "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", ...
```

In the second case, lacking this detail, the compiler thinks you might pass *any* format specifier, so the entire `scanf()` set of conversions needs to be in code.

```
const char *format
sscanf(s, format, ...
```